# Keyboard shortcut expansions not being expanded

Tags: ios, keyboard

I have defined several keywords on my iPad Air 2 (iOS 8.3) in order to let iOS expand them when I type one of these keywords.

However, these keywords do not expand. How can I force my iPad to expand them?

Comment: Just to be certain - you do have Settings > General > Keyboards > Auto-Correction on? [while you're there, check the shortcuts have synced] I wonder whether predictive needs to be on, too, similar to on the Mac where it will offer suggestions inc defined replacements sooner if you have auto spell correct on than if you don't...

Comment: Yes Auto correction in ON and the shortcuts have synced.

Comment: I'd be tempted to do the 'usual suspects' then - Reboot if you didn't already; then, in iTunes, sync, backup, restore…. just to see if it needs a gentle shove in the right direction - the old 'switch it off & back on again' ploy ;)

Comment: I will have to give that a try I guess. I'll let you know The result.

Comment: Welcome, wish you luck - keep us updated :) Add @name [the SE system will assist] to alert any one [not more than one] commenter to a new comment you post.

Comment: @Tetsujin tried everything. No succes :-(

Comment: ah, sorry - not sure what else to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

- Some apps do not support iOS keyboard shortcuts, having disabled autocomplete. Try using a first-party iOS app and see if the shortcuts work.
- Make sure you have defined the shortcuts in the right way, whereby the "Replace" is what you type and the "With" is what the autocomplete should fill, not the other way round.

Comment: The shortcut definitions are correct (they sync with my iPhone and my Mac). On my iPhone and Mac they do expand as expected in the native Notes app or in the native Email app. On my iPad however they do not expand in the apps mentioned. :-(